# Mp4 downloading instead of playing in Safari

Tags: ios, html, html5-video

I am facing a wierd issue in iOS devices. I am using a flowplayer which has mp4 file working in desktops. When it comes to iphone and ipad, the video is not playing. The same file taken from (http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4) is opening in browser but when uploaded to my server is not playing.

I tried to troublehsoot with Mac Safari. The file at internet location is playing in browser but the same file uploaded to my server is getting downloaded.

I doubt there is something wrong with headers in request or respose. Any help ?

Comment: Could you put a link or the code used to integrate the video in your site ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got the answer. My server does nt have the MIME type for mp4 and it was serving the video as application/octet.. I changed to video/mp4 and it worked :)