# How do servlet/grails correctly serve mp4 files to Safari?

Tags: java, servlets, grails, safari, video-streaming

In this simple code :

```
def index() {
    def file = new File('/tmp/big_buck_bunny_720p_50mb.mp4')
    println "file = ${file} , length = ${file.length()}"

    if (file.exists()) {
      webRequest.renderView = false;
      response.setContentType("video/mp4")
      response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + URLEncoder.encode(file.name, "UTF-8"));
      response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));

      InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

      response.outputStream << is
      response.outputStream.flush()
      response.outputStream.close()
      is.close()
    }
  } // index
```

It can correctly serve mp4 file to Firefox , but in Safari (9.0.1 on OS/X) , it's not playing , and the server reports :

```
file = /tmp/big_buck_bunny_720p_50mb.mp4 , length = 52464391
| Error 2015-11-23 10:37:13,339 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - SocketException occurred when processing request: [GET] /hello2/stream/index
Broken pipe. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Broken pipe
    Line | Method
->>  109 | socketWrite in java.net.SocketOutputStream
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    153 | write       in     ''
|     17 | index . . . in hello2.StreamController$$EPUpAtg0
|    198 | doFilter    in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1142 | runWorker   in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run         in java.lang.Thread
| Error 2015-11-23 10:37:13,349 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - IllegalStateException occurred when processing request: [GET] /hello2/stream/index
getOutputStream() has already been called for this response. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Error processing GroovyPageView: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    Line | Method
->>  648 | doFilter  in /hello2/grails-app/views/error.gsp
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
Caused by IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
->>  100 | flush     in java.io.FilterWriter
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    198 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
| Error 2015-11-23 10:37:13,354 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] ERROR [/hello2].[grails]  - Servlet.service() for servlet grails threw exception
```

Why the code works in Firefox but throws **Broken pipe** or **getOutputStream() has already been called for this response** exception in Safari ?

How to fix it ? Thanks.

Environments : Grails 2.5.1

===== updated =====

I found this question :

[Mp4 downloading instead of playing in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27296898/mp4-downloading-instead-of-playing-in-safari?lq=1) , and there is an URL http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4

My Safari can successfully play the video.

I try to simulate the header

```
$ curl -I http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.1 (Ubuntu)
Date: Mon, 23 Nov 2015 04:25:36 GMT
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Length: 383631
Last-Modified: Sun, 16 Feb 2014 18:49:36 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "53010840-5da8f"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Except the ETag , other headers are inserted.
But Safari still cannot play , and server reports same exception .

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-podpress-mp4-video-cant-play-on-safari

Comment: Hi , In this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27296898/mp4-downloading-instead-of-playing-in-safari , I can success play the mp4 file in safari : http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who is interested (or bogged down) in this question , I've found the solution. It's not a simple solution.

The solution is in this URL : [FileServlet supporting resume and caching and GZIP](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html)

It works for both servlet and Grails.