# Laravel Video Play

Tags: php, laravel, video, laravel-5

I have a issue here for video player in Laravel and cant understad why file is not supported.Videos are saved in DB with name and .mp4 extenision, here is my code

```
  @foreach($videos as $video)

                <div class="portfolio-item {{$video->id_category}}"><!-- item -->

                    <div class="margin-bottom-50">
                        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 thumbnail">
                            <video style="width: 100%" controls>
                                <source src=".....\lecture_videos/{{$video->filename}}" type="video/mp4">
                                Your browser does not support the audio element.
                            </video>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <h4 class="size-15">
                        <a target="_blank" href="{{url('video', $video->id)}}"><!--<span class="label label-danger pull-right">new</span>-->{{$video->title}}</a>
                    </h4>

                </div><!-- /item -->

            @endforeach
```

Chrome shows me somthing like this and it is not able to be played[image]

Comment: Is it actually an MP4? What does the browser's error console say?

Comment: what is your full path video in source src attribute?

Comment: src attriubte is "<source src="\a_panel\public\assets\attachments\lecture_videos/{{$video->filename}}" type="video/mp4"> " and browser console has no error.

Comment: Aren't your slashes pointing the wrong way? \ vs /?

Comment: @DouwedeHaan doesnt metter, it get the filename.mp4 but dont open it as a video

Comment: Are you able to copy/paste that `src` into the browser and view the video directly?

Comment: @ceejayoz when i try that it gives me a direct download link

Comment: @User154584 Does the file have a `video/mp4` mime type when downloading? Might be the sort of issue at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27296898/mp4-downloading-instead-of-playing-in-safari

Comment: do you test it in firefox?